# is applicationresources.properties file is common for all versions of Google app engine project like crons do?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, application-resource

I know that the cron is common for all the versions of an google app engine application, but is applicationresources.properties file also common for all the version. I mean if i change the applicationresources.properties file and then deploy to non-default version, will it override the default version?

Comment: Corns only run in the default version. Otherwise you'll run each cron X number of versions.

Comment: so you mean to say if I make changes to the cron and deploy the app to the non-default version, it will not override the cron of the default version?

Comment: In that sense they are shared. But it will run only on one version, which is the version default by default. So you can upload a version with a cron.yaml which will override the previous cron.yaml but will still be run on default.